# how to add stylesheet to my layout and pass values from view to layout

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, layout

I am using zend framework.

My structure is (only included files and folders needed for this question):

```
application
  >configs
  >controllers
  >forms
  >images
  >layouts
    >scripts
      >layout.phtml
  >models
  >styles
    >style.css
  >views
    >scripts
      >index
        >index.phtml
  Bootstrap.php
docs
library
logs
public
test
```

I have got the layout working properly. However, I want to ask a couple of questions in order to get my set up perfect for the way I want it.

1. Is `application>style`s a good place for the stylesheet to be? If not what's the recommended?
2. How do i add the stylesheet to the layout?
3. In my layout I have a title tag : `<title>Text</title>`. How do I pass values from my controllers to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stylesheets need to be accessible from the browser, so typically you will put these somewhere in the public directory, such as *public/css*
2. There are several ways, including placing rel tags in your view/layout, but my preferred option is to use the `viewHelper` within your controller:

   $this->view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/style.css');
   Then your call to `headLink()` in the layout file will automatically include the stylesheet.
3. The way I have done this is to use the Zend_Registry in the past.  There may be better ways.

Comment: Re: (3): setting `<title>` from controller: In controller, you can call `$this->view->headTitle()->prepend('My Title')` (or append, as you prefer). Alternatively, you can simply pass the title to the view using something like `$this->view->pageTitle` and then let the layout make the `headTitle()` call. Personally, I prefer the latter since rendering a title tag strikes me as a view-ish thing.